# How to bind Observable Collection and Save to Database

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, observablecollection

I will be doing an MVVM Project soon and I'm working a couple tutorial/examples out. How do I take the following code and connect it to a database. If I were to have a datagrid, how can I change information in the datagrid and have it automatically update? I'll be using MS SQL. Thanks for any tips or advice.

```
Class Person 

  Property _name As Integer
Property Name As Integer
    Get
        Return _name
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        _name = value
        RaisePropertyChanged("Name")

    End Set
End Property
End class
```

---

Then in another class:

```
Class Collections

Public namelist As New ObservableCollection(Of Person)

    namelist.Add(New Person With {.Name = Nothing})
```

--- Then in XAML

```
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="test" ObjectType="{x:Type local:Collections}"

     <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source= {StaticResource test}}">

      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Sample, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

  ect...ect....ect...
```

Now where or how do I connect my MS SQL table to all this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you're using MVVM, then your bindings (if wired properly) will propagate changes you make in the GridView to the properties their bound too if you wire the events when a cell edit is finished, etc.

Here's a source on that:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=563

I'm coming from a C# only background but,

for instance if you have a property of an observable collection:

```
 public ObservableCollection<string> Collection {get; set;}
```

on the ViewModel, if you had bound your view (the .xaml) to the VM by setting the DataContext of the View, and you had bound this OC to a combobox changing the selectedValue on the combobox would update the SelectedValue you bound to in the .xaml.

So if you had chosen for this combobox to be bound on SelectedValue to a property:

```
 public string SelectedValue {get; set;}
```

when you selected one of the choices in the combobox would update that value on the view model and it would step into the set portion of the property.

The same goes for whatever you have bound to the GridView.  If you have an ObservableCollection that your gridview binds too, you'll need to wire up the events on the view for when you feel a change should update the ViewModel and use the ICommand to propagate the change to the VM.

Another question would be are you required to use VB?  I know the frameworks that make MVVM easier like Caliburn.Micro are in C#, there must be some frameworks out there to make MVVM easy with VB.  Although with what you're trying, basic MVVM wouldn't be that hard to setup, these frameworks usually save you time from having to wire up the bindings manually.

Comment: Is there some reason the language in which your chosen MVVM framework is implemented effects the language in which you write your project? C# and VB.NET coexist just fine, short of source files in the same project...

Comment: Thanks for reply, yea it does have to be in VB. I understand what your talking about how it works and updates in the view. I'm still confused about the how these changes are saved in the database though. Like for example, if I have a datagrid and I input info in multiple rows. Would I have to iterate through the datagrid and add/update the table in the db? There's no way of just connecting the db table directly to the datagrid and have it save automatically or by a save button event?

Comment: In your class on the update (set) of the property you update the db.

Comment: One more important thing.  DO NOT update the DB directly from your VM.  Have the VM use a service (really just a class you create) that does this solely.  Your VM should only call into this class/service and that class/service will handle talking to the DB, separation of concerns.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can add Caliburn.Micro into a VB WPF project.  Might as well try, use NuGet and import Caliburn.Micro and see if it works, or see if it's even available, not sure if NuGet for VB can access the same libraries, guessing it can.

Comment: also, if you feel the answer and my comments after ward helped you understand the problem then accept the answer. thanks.

Comment: Yea np thx, I think I understand. SO basically I just need to create a class and maybe have a update/delete/ect.. function? And then call that in the view model when I need to? Also is Caliburn Micro a framework pattern for vs10 or something?

Comment: Caliburn.Micro is just a pre-built MVVM framework that installs into your project.  There's basic documentation on its codeplex site, beyond that there's a lot of articles out there on how to use it.  Yes you need a class (we call them services) that talks to the db, however you want, I usually use an ORM like Entity or LINQtoSql, up to you.  If you're really interested in doing it the right way look up the Repository pattern in .NET, this is the best way to interact with a db.